Is striving for excellence, even in worldly matters, a part of Islam? Does the word ihsaan mean excellence as well?
An AI bot presented to me the following hadith:
“Verily, Allah has prescribed excellence in all things. So, when you kill, kill well; when you slaughter, slaughter well. Let each one of you sharpen his knife and spare the animal pain.”  (Sahih Muslim 1907)
Although I found a completely different hadith on that number at sunnah.com, but when I searched those words on Google, I found the following Sahih Muslim hadith.

Shaddid b. Aus said:
Two are the things which I remember Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) having said:
Verily Allah has enjoined goodness to everything; so when you kill,
kill in a good way and when you slaughter, slaughter in a good way. So
every one of you should sharpen his knife, and let the slaughtered
animal die comfortably.
حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ،
حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ ابْنُ عُلَيَّةَ، عَنْ خَالِدٍ الْحَذَّاءِ،
عَنْ أَبِي قِلاَبَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي الأَشْعَثِ، عَنْ شَدَّادِ بْنِ
أَوْسٍ، قَالَ ثِنْتَانِ حَفِظْتُهُمَا عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله
عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ كَتَبَ الإِحْسَانَ عَلَى كُلِّ
شَىْءٍ فَإِذَا قَتَلْتُمْ فَأَحْسِنُوا الْقِتْلَةَ وَإِذَا ذَبَحْتُمْ
فَأَحْسِنُوا الذَّبْحَ وَلْيُحِدَّ أَحَدُكُمْ شَفْرَتَهُ فَلْيُرِحْ
ذَبِيحَتَهُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
Reference   : Sahih Muslim 1955a In-book reference
: Book 34, Hadith 84 USC-MSA web (English) reference   : Book 21,
Hadith 4810   (deprecated numbering scheme)
Source: https://sunnah.com/muslim:1955a

The confusion is that there appears to be a contradiction. The former appears to say that try our best to do everything we do in the most efficient and effective manner, i.e. striving for excellence (I am talking about worldly matters, e.g. one's job). However, the later appears to talk about showing kindness.
Can someone please elaborate on this, especially the word ihsaan with examples, to clarify if it really means striving for excellence, even in worldly matters?

There are multiple questions in your question. Also try not to add your personal issues in the question, no matter how dire they may seem. Alternatively you could add a general issue that would help a larger audience.

@AbduRahman Thank you for guidance and editing my question. JazakAllah. InshaAllah I'll keep this in mind in future.
